# How can i add libreoffice to Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, libreoffice

I have a dockerized nodejs application. I use libreoffice for converting to PDF.

How can I add libreoffice to dockerfile with nodejs app? And how can I make the app be able to use the libreoffice app?

```
FROM node:16.8.0-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN apk add --update python3 make g++ && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN npm install

# If you are building your code for production
#RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 80:80

CMD [ "node", "build/index.js","STAGING"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following to your Dockerfile should install libreoffice

```
RUN apk add libreoffice
```

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/libreoffice

Comment: Will it be enough to just add this command? Can I now use libreoffice in my Node.js application?

Comment: How are you using it? With the info you gave me I can only say that the above will add libreoffice to your docker container. If you use e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/libreoffice-convert then I believe this should be enough.

Comment: Wonderful, im using libreoffice-convert. I guess I just couldn't believe it could be this easy. Thank you Marius.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following line installs LibreOffice

```
RUN apk add libreoffice
```

It is also necessary to install Java Runtime Environment (JRE) in the container, which is required for LibreOffice to function correctly. Adding the following line installs the OpenJDK 8 JRE package on Alpine Linux.

```
RUN apk add openjdk8-jre
```

It is possible to run LibreOffice commands in a Node.js application without installing any additional libraries. You can use the `child_process` module in Node.js to execute any shell command. The `child_process` module provides several methods to spawn new child processes, which can be used to execute shell commands. In the following code, I have used the exec method to run the LibreOffice command.

```
// Importing the child_process module from the Node.js standard library
const { exec } = require("child_process");

// Importing the util module from the Node.js standard library
const util = require("util");

// Converting the exec function from a callback-based API to a Promise-based API
const execProm = util.promisify(exec);

// Defining a function to run a command using the execProm function
const runCommand = async (command) => {
  try {
    // Running the command using the execProm function and waiting for it to complete
    await execProm(command);
  } catch (ex) {
    // Handling any errors that occur while running the command
    console.error(ex);
  }
};

// Defining the output directory path
const outputPath = "./output/";

// Defining the input file path
const inputFilePath = "./file.pdf";

// Defining the command to be executed
const command = `soffice --infilter="impress_pdf_import" --convert-to pptx:"Impress MS PowerPoint 2007 XML" --outdir ${outputPath} ${inputFilePath}`;

// Defining a handler function to run the command
const handler = async () => {
  // Calling the runCommand function to execute the command
  await runCommand(command);
};

// Calling the handler function to start the command execution
handler();
```